# any is not identical to anyObject

Tags: swift

I've a payload getting shuttled from one part of the system to the other.

The shuttle is carrying the payload as Any, so I could carry any kind of objects including non objects like tuples, etc.

one of the parts of the system is accepting AnyObject so is the error.

I'm confused like what type to use to carry stuff around so it's compatible between all parts of the system.

Shall I make a choice and stick to one of the types, either Any or AnyObject for the system as a whole or what's the best choice for shuttling items if you are not concerned with their actual types.

we had type `Object` in other languages that could carry anything around, but not sure how this works in SWIFT world

or is there a casting that could work between the two? If I'm 100% convinced that the coming object is AnyObject, I could load it off from the shuttle (Any) as an AnyObject

**Note to negative voters:** Please help to clear up the question if it doesn't make any sense to you or help to improve this question, since I'm new to SWIFT. I need an answer not your vote.

***Edit***

a case where I had to do comparison between `Any` and `AnyObject` while unit testing, how would you handle such situation.

```
class Test {
    var name: String = "test"
}

var anyObject: AnyObject = Test()

var any: Any = anyObject

//XCTAssert(any == anyObject, "Expecting them to be equal")
any == anyObject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` will hold any kind of type, including structs and enums as well as classes.  `AnyObject` will only hold classes.  So what `Any` can store is a superset of what `AnyObject` can.  No amount of casting will cram your custom structs or enums into an `AnyObject`.

Sometimes it seems like `AnyObject` is holding a struct such as a `String`, but it isn’t, what has happened is somewhere along the way Swift has converted your `String` to an `NSString` (which is a class so can be stored in an `AnyObject`).

(technically, `Any` is defined as something that implements 0 or more protocols, which anything does, whereas `AnyObject` is defined as a special protocol all classes implicitly conform to, and that is marked as an `@objc` protocol, so only classes can conform to it)

edit: to answer your question about comparisons – there’s no `==` operator for `Any` or `AnyObject` (how would it work if you equated an `Any` containing a `String` to an `Any` containing an `Int`?).  You have to cast both sides back into what they really are before you can compare them using an appropriately-defined operator for that type.

Comment: thank you sir, I've edited with some more details on this to understand how to interoperate between the two, although I've decided to stick to `Any` everywhere in my system, so i doesn't create the conflict between the two while assigning and assigning back in

Comment: I've also noticed that any class instances/objects implicity becomes `AnyObject`

Comment: Updated to cover the edit (though really that’s a separate question, you should post separately).  I’d also strongly suggesting looking into generics or protocols rather than resorting to `Any` to pass your objects around.  There’s lots more info in the Apple Swift book.

Comment: okay, thanks, I read your post again and again and it makes sense, when you say you have to cast both sides back into what they really are before you can compare, you mean `any as? Test == anyObject as Test`

Comment: exactly - though you should use `as?` on both sides, one isn’t for `Any` and the other for `AnyObject`.  If you use `as` and the object isn’t of that type, you’ll get a runtime error.  Though bear in mind if you equate two optionals and they’re both nil they’ll both be equal – so if the conversion fails on both sides you’ll get a false success.

Comment: got you on the nil as well, the unit test assert works now, after casting them back to the actual type, thanks for the deep insight sir.